# Scatter-gather PublishSubscribe rollback on exception

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to create a scatter-gather that executes several handlers in separate transaction.
To do so, I assumed that the version with the PublishSubscribeChannel configured with a taskExecutor would be the most appropriate.
To managed errors, I followed the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/scatter-gather.html#scatter-gather-error-handling

Unfortunately, I must be missing something, as when an exception occurs in the handler, the transaction is not rolled-back.

To be more precised, in the above example the EaiAckNackOut object with satus "bar" has been persisted to the database.
Could you please help me to setup a proper rollback on exception ?

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DistributionScatterGather {

    @Configuration
    public static class ScatterGatherConfig {

        @Bean
        public PublishSubscribeChannel scatterGatherChannel(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
            return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe(taskExecutor).applySequence(true).get();
        }

    }

    private final PublishSubscribeChannel scatterGatherChannel;
    private final EaiAckNackOutRepository eaiAckNackOutRepository;

    @Bean
    MessageSource<String> msgSource() {
        return () -> new GenericMessage<>("foo");
    }

    @Bean
    GenericHandler<String> failedHandler() {
        return (payload, headers) -> {
            EaiAckNackOut eaiAckNackOut = new EaiAckNackOut();
            eaiAckNackOut.setStatus("foo");
            eaiAckNackOutRepository.save(eaiAckNackOut);
            log.info("FailedHandler processing: {}", payload);
            throw new RuntimeException("Error!");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    GenericHandler<String> successHandler() {
        return (payload, headers) -> {
            EaiAckNackOut eaiAckNackOut = new EaiAckNackOut();
            eaiAckNackOut.setStatus("bar");
            eaiAckNackOutRepository.save(eaiAckNackOut);
            log.info("SuccessHandler processing: {}", payload);
            return "Success";
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow scatterFlow() {
        return f -> f.publishSubscribeChannel(scatterGatherChannel,
                s -> s.subscribe(sf -> sf.handle(failedHandler()))
                        .subscribe(sf -> sf.handle(successHandler()))
        );
    }
    
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow distributionFlow(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        PollerSpec pollerSpec = Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .maxMessagesPerPoll(1);

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(msgSource(), c -> c.poller(pollerSpec).autoStartup(true))
                .log("org.eib.cms.connectivity.job.DistributionScatterGather", m -> "retrieved entity: " + m)
                .scatterGather(
                        scatterGatherChannel,
                        gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(new SimpleMessageGroupProcessor()),
                        scatterGather -> scatterGather.errorChannel("scatterGatherErrorChannel").gatherTimeout(10000)
                )
                .log("org.eib.cms.connectivity.job.DistributionScatterGather", m -> "Finished: " + m)
                .get();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "scatterGatherErrorChannel")
    public Message<?> processAsyncScatterError(MessagingException payload) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload("An error occured:" + payload.getCause())
                .copyHeaders(payload.getFailedMessage().getHeaders())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is expected, since your `PublishSubscribeChannel` is fully async and publishes message to its subscribers on different thread. So, failure in your `failedHandler` does not effect a behavior in the `successHandler`. just because they happen on different threads and they are fully not involved in the same transaction. Of course, for a reason because transaction is thread-tied.

I'm not sure how to help you here because the Scatter-Gather is really not for this scenarios. Its scatter goal is to distribute message into isolated services. In your case it looks like one service depends on the outcome of another.

Comment: Apologies, I made a typo in _EaiAckNackOut object with satus "bar" has been persisted to the database_ should have been _EaiAckNackOut object with satus "_*foo*_" has been persisted to the database_ which is more in line with isolated services. 

In the meantime found the source of my problem. In my real implementation, I have an abstract class for my handlers which extends GenericHandler. But this abstract class did not annotate the method `handle(S payload, MessageHeaders headers)` with `@Transactional` and consequently the handlers were not CGLIB proxied.

Comment: Well, for that task see a second argument of the `handle()`, So, you probably just need to add `transactional()`  into that endpoint configurer.